# Projecting image from computer that is a distance away

Tags: video, laptop, projector

For our schools theatrical production class, we need to project an image using a projector, however the only way to use the projector is to hang it on a lighting bar (Not a problem)  The problem is that we do not have a long enough VGA cord to hook that projector up to a laptop/desktop.  I have called around and asked about a 200ft VGA cable, but at that length that would loose signal.  So I thought I would ask this form what would be the best solution to my problem.  I have thought about getting a 200 coax cable with VGA ends, but is that even possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to amplify VGA for long runs, but since that's an analog signal it's usually not the best option. VGA over coax is probably more trouble than it's worth (you'd have to merge the many VGA channels somehow to use the single coax pin, and then reverse it).

VGA over Cat5e is fairly common. You still aren't running an analog signal over 200ft, but there's hardware to convert from VGA to a digital signal and then convert back at the other end with minimal latency. For example, [this product](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001PBO5YK), which also has a monitor port at the source end.

A less reliable option, but possibly less pricey if your projector supports it, is wireless projection over wi-fi. But like I said, this may be not reliable enough for theater application.

Comment: What about something like this combo (With a 200ft Cat5e) [link](http://www.amazon.com/Video-Extender-CAT5-Cable-Adapter/dp/B005QVXXZC/ref=pd_sim_e_22) and [link](http://www.amazon.com/Tripp-Lite-B132-100A-Extender-B132-004A/dp/B00292BSL2/ref=pd_sim_e_12)

Comment: Not going to work in a million years. The second link is just the remote unit for the product I linked to in my post--it requires the base unit, which is powered and is going to encode your VGA signal digitally. The first link is just a straight analog converter at each end. If they work at all, the quality is going to be worse and MUCH more susceptible to interference over a 100ft+ unshielded cat5e run.

Comment: Alright, I understand.  I was just trying to find some cheaper options.  But if the product you linked me is the one you think is best, We'll order it.

Comment: [This one](http://www.amazon.com/Tripp-Lite-B130-101-Extender-Remote/dp/B001U8UAB0/ref=pd_cp_e_0) is a little less expensive since it doesn't include the audio (which I imagine you won't need). If I was doing technical direction for a show that required this on a budget, that's probably what I would purchase; knowing that Tripp-Lite is a reputable brand, and that the product is highly rated on Amazon. The real professional quality stuff (and thus, professionally-priced) can be found [here](http://www.markertek.com/CATV-Headend-Interface/CAT-5-Transmission-Systems/VGA-Over-CAT5-Systems.xhtml).

Comment: Perfect!  Yes, we would never use the audio in the converter, as the computer is running in the tech booth we would have our own audio system set up.